# Git log of all branchs in only the current tree

Tags: git, git-branch, git-log

I want to get the log of all branch in **only** the current tree.

**Long story**

Given the git history below:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 3d0cb35 (HEAD, master) 4th commit
| * a43b07c (branch) 4th commit in branch
|/  
* 722745a 3rd commit
* 46d0d84 2nd commit
* 3060fe0 1st commit
```

Let say that I create a orphan branch.

```
$ git checkout --orphan orphan
Switched to a new branch 'orphan'
```

Add a commit in orphan branch and try to use the first command to get git history of the "second" tree.

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* 202f3c4 (HEAD, orphan) Orphan branch
* 3d0cb35 (master) 4th commit
| * a43b07c (branch) 4th commit in branch
|/  
* 722745a 3rd commit
* 46d0d84 2nd commit
* 3060fe0 1st commit
```

In the sample above, look like that `3d0cb35` is the father of `202f3c4` what isn't true. How can I get only the commit of **only** one of the trees?

Comment: @Useless I think you need to check the description of `--orphan` in `git help checkout`. The results of the above scenario are that commit `202f3c4` has *no* parents - it is an orphan, and the root of another DAG that may eventually have several distinct branches in it... The output of `git log` admittedly doesn't make that extremely clear...

Comment: Thanks, brain re-engaged ...

Comment: The `--oneline` graph is just slightly defective in that it does not have a way to represent a "stop point" when drawing disconnected commit diagrams.  Run the same `git log --graph` but without `--oneline` and you will see that git does in fact know that these are different commit DAGs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a completely clean way to do what you want. But here's one suggestion... If you know that the set of branches you want to inspect is the one rooted at commit `3060fe0`, then you can use `git branch --contains 3060fe0` to identify the potential branches, and use that to feed your `git log` command. Something like:

```
git log ..... `git branch --contains 3060fe0`
```

But leave out the `--all` option, as that would override your explicit branch selection...

For convenience, you could drop a tag on each tree root, like `git tag tree1 3060fe0`, then you could just use `git branch --contains tree1`.

Comment: To make this work in all cases: `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1` will find the root commit for the HEAD commit, and then `git branch --contains` the result of that will get you all branches whose root is this root.

Comment: @torek That would work, as long as you want to inspect the tree you are currently in. However, if you want to look at the other tree, it won't help...

Comment: True, but the OP said "current tree", which I translated to "graph rooted at commit that is root of `HEAD`".  I do like the tag-on-each-"interesting"-root idea, it seems like a cleaner way to invoke this.

Comment: Note that listing branches using `git branch` will mark the current branch with an asterisk, which will mess everything up when you try to feed to to `git log`... here's what I came up with for showing the log graph with all branches for the current tree: `git log --oneline --graph --decorate $(git branch --contains $(git rev-list -n1 HEAD) | tr -d ' *')`

Comment: Combining the answers together with the `-a` flag too, and I was able to clean up the output with: `git log --decorate --graph $(git branch --color=never -a --contains $(git rev-list HEAD | tail -n1) | sed 's|^..||; s| -> .*||')`. I used `sed` instead of `tr` because "pointer" refs have a `->` in the output of `git branch`, and since branches can't contain spaces, I'm able to clean that up unambiguously.